# Is kinetic energy in infinite square well conserved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum, energy-conservation, schroedinger-equation

First we know that $\langle\hat{p}\rangle$ is not conserved, since the potential $V(x)$ is not invariant under translations therefore $\hat{p}$ does not commute with $\hat{H}$. Thus $T=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$ does not commute with $\hat{H}$ either, since the former share the same set of eigenfunctions with $\hat{p}$. So according to Heisenberg Equation, kinetic energy is not conserved.

However, $\langle T\rangle=\langle H\rangle$ by virtue of infinite square well, so it seems that $\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle T\rangle}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle H\rangle}{\mathrm{d}t}=0$ ? Where am I wrong?

Furthermore, I would like to ask why it requires $[\hat{H},\hat{Q}]=0$ to say that $Q$ is conserved? As far as I see, as long as $[\hat{H},\hat{Q}]f=0$ for any $f$ that satisfies Schrödinger Equation instead of any $f$ in Hilbert Space, we can derive $\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle Q\rangle}{\mathrm{d}t}=0$. (Assume $\hat{Q}$ does not depend explicitly on $t$.)

Answer (score 6):

Obviously the energy is conserved: $$H(t)= e^{itH/\hbar}He^{-itH/\hbar}=H\:,$$
since functions of a given selfadjoint operator (here the Hamiltonian $H=T$) always commute. There is no potential energy here. Physically speaking, the presence of an infinite well is embodied in the boundary conditions which make $H$ (essentially) selfadjoint: the admitted functions in the domain of $H$ vanish at the boundary.

Regarding the momentum operator, it simply does not exist *as a selfadjoint operator* in the infinite well (imposing vanishing boundary conditions we do not have a selfadjoint operator contrarily to $H$).

Finally, the requirement $[Q,H]=0$, with some technical  mathematical  hypotheses implies that $Q$ is conserved $$Q(t)= e^{itH/\hbar}Qe^{-itH/\hbar}=Q\:.$$ Also the converse inplication is true, so that, under suitable hypotheses, $[Q,H]=0$ is equivalent to the conservation of $Q$ along the dynamics generated by $H$.

Comment: @DanielC thank you for correcting various typos (not only this time). I was writing from my phone and in a hurry....

Answer (score 4):

The momentum opertor $\hat p$ does not have *any* eigenfunctions in an infinite square well because $\hat p\psi=k\psi$ would require $\psi= e^{ikx}$, and there is no value of $k$ susch that $\psi(0)=\psi(L)=0$.

Comment: Err what about psi = sin(kx), then k=pi*n/L.   (n integer value)

Comment: @dllahr It is obviously not an eigenfunction of $P$.

Comment: Oh my bad, how about instead psi = A[exp(ikx) - exp(-ikx)]

Comment: @dllahr This is proportional to the $\sin$, again.

Comment: Exactly.  And each component is an eigenfunction of p-hat, and it's a linear operator so a linear combination of them is an eigenfunction of the operator, ergo ...

Comment: No: A linear combination of eigenfunctions with different eigenvalues (here +k and - k)  is *not* an eigenfunction.

Answer (score 3):

> since the former share the same set of eigenfunctions with $\hat{p}$. So according to Heisenberg Equation, kinetic energy is not conserved.

For the "particle-in-a-box," eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are eigenfunctions of the kinetic energy, but are *not* eigenfunctions of the momentum.

We know that the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are:
$$
\phi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\;,
$$
inside the box, and $\phi_n=0$ outside the box.

Acting $\hat p$ on $\phi_n$ gives:
$$
\hat p \phi_n(x) = -i\hbar\frac{\pi n}{L}\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\;,
$$
the RHS of which has a $\cos$ not a $\sin$, so $\phi_n$ is *not* an eigenfunction of $\hat p$.

Acting $\hat p^2$ on $\phi_n$ gives:
$$
\hat p \hat p \phi_n(x) = -(-i\hbar)^2(\frac{\pi n}{L})^2\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) = \frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2 n^2}{L^2}\phi_n\;.
$$
So, we see that $\phi_n$ *is* an eigenfunction of $\hat p^2$ and therefore $\phi_n$ is an eigenfunction of $\hat T$. This should also be clear from the fact that $H=T$ everywhere that $\phi_n$ is not zero.

> However, $\langle T\rangle=\langle H\rangle$ by virtue of infinite square well, so it seems that $\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle T\rangle}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle H\rangle}{\mathrm{d}t}=0$ ? Where am I wrong?

You are not wrong.

---

**Update:**

Because of the toy nature of the particle-in-a-box model, kinetic energy is conserved. Momentum is not generally conserved.

Kinetic energy is conserved because the Hamiltonian is effectively equal to the kinetic energy (the potential effectively just enforces the toy model boundary condition).

Below, I consider momentum.

For *any* eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian $\phi_n$:
$$
p_{nn} = \langle \phi_n|\hat p|\phi_n\rangle = 0\;.
$$

We also have:
$$
p_{nm} = - p_{mn}=p_{mn}^*\;.
$$

More explicitly:
$$
p_{r+q,r} = \langle \phi_{r+q}|\hat p|\phi_r\rangle = \frac{4\hbar r(r+q)}{iq(2r+q)}\;,
$$
when $q$ is odd, and zero otherwise.

The most general solution to the Schrodinger equation that we can write down for this toy model is:
$$
\Psi(x,t) = \sum_n a_n e^{-i\epsilon_n t/\hbar} \phi_n(x)\;,
$$
where $\epsilon_n=\frac{\hbar^2n^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}$ and $a_n$ is $\int dx \phi_n\Psi(x,0)$.

For this most general state, we have:
$$
p(t) = \langle \Psi|\hat p|\Psi\rangle
=\sum_{n,r}a_n^*a_r p_{nr}e^{it(\epsilon_n-\epsilon_r)/\hbar}
$$
$$
=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\sum_{q=-r + 1; {odd}}^{\infty} a_{r+q}^* a_r \frac{4\hbar r(r+q)}{iq(2r+q)} e^{it\pi^2\hbar q(2r+q)/2mL^2}
$$

For example, suppose I have a state $\Psi(x, 0)$ at $t=0$ with
$$
a_1 = i/\sqrt{2}
$$
and
$$
a_2 = 1/\sqrt{2}\;.
$$

Then, the time dependence of the momentum would look like:
$$
p(t) = \frac{i}{2}p_{12}(2\cos(\Delta t)/\hbar) = -\frac{i}{2}p_{1+1,1}(2\cos(t\Delta))
=-\frac{8\hbar}{3}\cos(\Delta t/\hbar)\;,
$$
where $\Delta = \epsilon_2 - \epsilon_1$.

Comment: yes I noticed this as I calculated $\langle T\rangle$, but can we explain it using commutation? (Only commutator appears in Heisenberg Equation, not eigenfunctions. I can't see how $\hat{p}^2$ and $\hat{H}$ commute?

Comment: They don't commute everywhere, but they commute "almost everywhere" since $dV/dx$ is only non-zero at two points.

Comment: $[p^2, H] = [p^2, V] = -i\hbar\left(p\frac{dV}{dx} + \frac{dV}{dx}p\right)$

Comment: But $\hat{p}$ and $V$ commute "almost everywhere" too. What's the difference?

Comment: Not much difference really. Stationary states are always composed of two plane waves of equal and opposite momenta.

Comment: And there's another problem, $\hat{p}\phi$ is a cosine inside the well, and for the outside part it is 0, so there's a discontinuous point at the edge of the well. If we differentiate again we get two $\delta$s.  I know that if two functions are "almost everywhere" equivalent then they are the same element in $L^2(X)$ space, but here we have two $\delta$s so I think we cannot apply this. So, "Eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are eigenfunctions of the kinetic energy" is it correct?

Comment: "So, "Eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are eigenfunctions of the kinetic energy" is it correct?" Yes, this is correct. The particle-in-a-box is a toy model where the Hamiltonian is effectively equal to the kinetic energy (the "potential" effectively just enforces the toy model boundary conditions). You can see that the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are eigenfunctions of the kinetic energy in exactly the way I demonstrated in my answer (by acting $\frac{-\hbar^2\nabla^2}{2m}$ on them and seeing that the results is the same function multiplied by a constant).

Comment: @wanghr I updated my answer. The momentum of any eigenstate is also conserved and is also equal to zero (because of how the eigenstates have to be constructed). The momentum of a general state does not have to be conserved, but the kinetic energy does.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really cogent argument and reminds me of an exercise in Griffith's book. But actually I'm more curious about what happened in $\frac{\mathrm{d}\langle T\rangle}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{1}{2mi\hbar}\langle[\hat{p}^2,\hat{H}]\rangle$, why it is ineffective. I noticed that as we deduce it we changed the order of integration and differentiation, which requires really decent properties of the operators and functions, and that's really doubtful for infinite wells.

Comment: Besides, it seems that even for finite wells the commutator $[\hat{p}^2,\hat{H}]$ is not hermitian, and it's suspicious to calculate its expectation. Are these probable reasons to the problem?

Comment: It might be better to just consider the "particle-in-a-box" as a toy problem where the schrodinger equation is solved on the finite interval [0,L] subject to the boundary conditions that the wavefunction is zero at the boundary. This removes the need to consider derivatives of delta functions and whatnot. An alternative way might be to consider the finite well and look at what happens as the well size gets big.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument that if $A$ doesnt commute with $H$ so this also applies to $A^2$ is wrong. For example, in a 2 dimentions, suppose A is $\begin{pmatrix} 1\ 0\\ 0\ -1\end{pmatrix}$ then $A^2$ commutes with everything (the identity matrix)

Comment: You're right, but I still don't see how can $[\hat{p}^2$ commute with $\hat{H}$?